# Did you think you .... me somewhere before?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-continuous

> Did you think you ....  me somewhere before?

options:

> a) have seen
>   b) had seen
>   c) were seeing

My approach:

I am confused between "were seeing" (c) VS "have seen" (a).

I think **have seen** should be there because it is used with the words "ever","never","before".

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you're trying to decide between both wrong answers.

> Did you think you **had seen** me somewhere before?

I don't know who taught you these rules that "have" is only used with "ever," "never," and "before," but that's incorrect. This isn't present perfect tense, so we shouldn't use "have" in this case.

"Were seeing" is not applicable because it would not make much sense in context. Past continuous tense is used to express that you were doing something over a period of time in the past. It didn't happen instantly. "Did you think you were seeing me somewhere before?" implies one of two things. Either the person the speaker is talking to stared at the speaker for a long period of time somewhere else, or the speaker is trying to clarify that they aren't dating ("seeing" is a colloquialism for "dating"), contrary to the other person's understanding. Also, "somewhere before" implies that the event happened once at a particular location, not continuously.

Comment: WHAT?!  Had is singular?  Are you confusing it with "has"?

Comment: Sorry, I have brainfarts. I think that's more of what I was trying to say. also, I didn't look at your answer before editing mine, Victor.

Answer (score 3):

Because the question is in Past Tense, the only correct choice (from those you gave) is

> Did you think you **had seen** me somewhere before?

You can't use "*were seeing*" because it is continuous.  You can't use "*have seen*" because that is Present tense.